# How do I add the buttons from one class to another class

Tags: java, class, button

What I have been trying to do is add the Buttons located in the Players class to the footballField class. When I add the buttons to the footballFiel class in the Control panel class the Buttons do not appear. The Players class has a null layout design and the control panel has 2 panels with a border layout design. How can I make the buttons of one class appear in another? My overall goal is to create a football game :

```
    public class ControlPanel extends JPanel{

private Players footballPlayers;
private FootBallField footField;
private Score scoreBoard;

private TimerSetup Timer;



ControlPanel(){
    super();
 // This is the scoreboard clas
 scoreBoard = new Score(); 
 // The players class
 footballPlayers = new Players();

 //The football player class object is created
 footField = new FootBallField(footballPlayers);
 Timer = new TimerSetup(footballPlayers);

 //The field is added
 //The scoreboard is added
 setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 add(footField,"Center");
 add(scoreBoard,"North");

 footField.add(footballPlayers);

}

Players(){

          setLayout(null); 
          movablePlayer();
          addMachinePlayers();

    }

public void movablePlayer(){
     //Assigns image to variable Player Image
    playerImage = new ImageIcon("Images/footballPlayer.jpg");
    //FootballPlayer button is added
    footBallPlayer = new JButton();  
    add(footBallPlayer); 
    footBallPlayer.setIcon(playerImage);
    footBallPlayer.setOpaque(false);
    footBallPlayer.setBounds(new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50)); 
    setFocusable(true); 
    addKeyListener(this); 
    requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

public void addMachinePlayers(){

```
    // Bot 1
    machinePlayers.add(new JButton("Bot1"));
    //machinePlayers.get(0).setIcon(playerImage);
    machinePlayers.get(0).setBounds(100,100,100,100);
    add(machinePlayers.get(0));
    // Bot 2

    machinePlayers.add(new JButton("Bot2"));
    //machinePlayers.get(0).setIcon(playerImage);
    machinePlayers.get(1).setBounds(100,200,100,100);
    add(machinePlayers.get(1));

    //Bot 3   
}
```

Comment: It's probably the null layout that's messing you up.  Use a simple (FlowLayout? BoxLayout?) layout and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks I used the Boxlayout!